# Thresholding infrared images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to analyze infrared images of solar panels and cut the panels from the images. As a first step I need to threshold the image. But if I do it with a example image from google like the one below I only get a black image. What I can do to improve?

[image: picture]

[image: bad image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('GooglePanelIR.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(hsv[:,:,0],100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('cont imge', thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print(ret)
```

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Your image is a single (grey) channel, repeated three times to make an RGB image which is just grey. It has no colour. There is no point converting to HSV because there are no Hues or Saturations in it. So get rid of the `cvtColor()` line and change the following line to `ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img[0],100...)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. Of course. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Suraj has got it done for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to threshold and its a grayscale image, import your image in grayscale.

This is what you are looking for.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('GooglePanelIR.png', 0)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('cont imge', thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print(ret)
```